# apt document containing list of installable packages

Tags: apt

Is there online a textual (simple text, HTML, pdf...), updated document where it is listed all the software I can install using `apt-get install`?

Answer (score 13):

The [Ubuntu Package Index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) lists available packages in the official repositories, their versions, the repositories they belong to, and other such details. There are links for browsing through available packages. The list of all packages is also available for each currently supported release (for example, the list for 14.04: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/allpackages - beware, it's ***very*** long).

Comment: Using `wget -O- "http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/allpackages?format=txt.gz" | gzip -d | wc -l` and minus six header lines, it contains 53803 packages.

Answer (score 7):

You can obtain a list of all the packages available by typing the command:

```
apt-cache search .
```

Answer (score -3):

The command we need to use is `dpkg --get-selections`, which will give us a list of all the currently installed packages.

```
$ dpkg --get-selections
adduser                                         install
alsa-base                                       install
alsa-utils                                      install
apache2                                         install
apache2-mpm-prefork                             install
apache2-utils                                   install
apache2.2-common                                install
apt                                             install
apt-utils                                       install
```

Comment: The question states all packages available for installation, not only those already installed.