# Cannot find repo package list online?

Tags: repository, ubuntu-website

I'm thinking of switching from Arch Linux to Ubuntu. I was gonna start with the Server version so I can build everything up from minimal, work i3-wm and have my wonderful system with Ubuntu!

I have a few programs that I like to use and I wanna see if Ubuntu has 'em. I'm sure it does but I wanna make sure. Unlike Arch Linux, Ubuntu doesn't appear to list its repositories anywhere so I won't know for sure if packages like dosbox-svn or wiznote are available. I am somewhat scared to dive in blind so I hope there is a way to view the goods before I buy.

Thanks very much for reading and I'm looking forward to a reply :-)

Comment: You might check here: http://packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: There is also an online 'Search'  http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gcc-5 ..... And a repo example  http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ → → →   http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/

Comment: Not really sure why you would want to switch to Ubuntu if you want to build your system from the ground up, Arch is really more suited for that as you'll soon find out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of all packages available for a specific version of Ubuntu (not necessarily the one I have installed)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/786121/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-packages-available-for-a-specific-version-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

The packages provided by the Ubuntu repositories can be found at http://packages.ubuntu.com/. If the packages you need cannot be found there, use your favorite search engine to search for PPAs (personal package archives) that host them. If such PPAs do not exist, then you will have to either download the debs and install them manually using `dpkg` or compile from source, both of which should be straightforward given your Arch Linux background.