# Required a dpkg status file

Tags: dpkg

We know that Ubuntu has 60,000 + packages.

I may not require all those but want a dpkg status file containing all the possible packages information listed.

I have a customized Linux where I manually hardcoded the utilities unlike installing through apt. So I don't have a status file with the packages.
Now I want to create it manually so that when I query for the list of packages it gives the information of the utilities/packages what I have.

If I can get the status file with all the possible packages available for Ubuntu structured in a standard format like below, then I can edit that file and use it on my machine.

example format:

```
Package: libvorbisfile3
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 55
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: libvorbis
Version: 1.3.5-4.2
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libogg0 (>= 1.1.0), libvorbis0a (= 1.3.5-4.2)
Description: high-level API for Vorbis General Audio Compression Codec
 Ogg Vorbis is a fully open, non-proprietary, patent-and-royalty-free,
 general-purpose compressed audio format for audio and music at fixed
 and variable bitrates from 16 to 128 kbps/channel.
 .
 The Vorbisfile library provides a convenient high-level API for decoding
 and basic manipulation of all Vorbis I audio streams.
Original-Maintainer: Debian Xiph.org Maintainers 
Homepage: http://www.xiph.org/vorbis/
```

Answer (score 1):

The files in that format are located in /var/lib/apt/lists.

Comment: I know where they are located.But I want all the packages that ubuntu has. NOt inparticular for my desktop ubuntu. If ubuntu has 60,000+ packages lets say I need information on all these 60000 packages

Comment: That's what is in those files. The file for a specific repo/pocket includes ALL the packages in that repo/pocket.

Comment: @sid that's right you need to enable all channels and repositories or if you don't want to change your system check `chdist` as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly that format but a close one that could be modified:

```
Package: libvorbisfile3
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 59
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Xiph.org Maintainers <pkg-xiph-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Source: libvorbis
Version: 1.3.5-3
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libogg0 (>= 1.1.0), libvorbis0a (= 1.3.5-3)
Filename: pool/main/libv/libvorbis/libvorbisfile3_1.3.5-3_amd64.deb
Size: 15876
MD5sum: b28aab7326b5ed38bd0891923ad0f234
SHA1: 07b978b831d4a47cf5b1efa5fd62a0bb7981902c
SHA256: bfd6eec22191bffef0874d8890afd6503c2ca541abc2b2b1e44e80135f7fd0af
Description: high-level API for Vorbis General Audio Compression Codec
Multi-Arch: same
Homepage: http://www.xiph.org/vorbis/
Description-md5: 12cd648fe3db0c63fff144f4ce158c03
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
Task: ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-usb, kubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-full, edubuntu-desktop, edubuntu-usb, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, mythbuntu-frontend, mythbuntu-desktop, lubuntu-core, ubuntustudio-desktop-core, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntu-gnome-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-mate-cloudtop
```

Every Debian/Ubuntu repository has package index which is split by release, channel and architecture, usually called `Packages.gz` or `Packages.xz`.

For your requirement, it should be enough. But to be complete there is also `Contents-arch.gz` which contains listing of all files in packages.

You can download them manually or using a tools like: `apt`, `apt-file` or more advanced tool like `chdist` (see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/791232/26246))